# MATLAB: Function Handle of Nested Function

Tags: matlab, function-handle

Is there a way to create a function handle to a nested function that includes the parent function in the function handle?

As an example, say I have:

```
function myP = myParent()

    myP.My_Method = myMethod;

    function myMethod()
        disp "hello world"
    end
end
```

In another file, I could call the method by doing something like:

```
myP = myParent();
myP.My_Method();
```

But, if I have another function that takes function handles as a parameter and then calls the function, how do I pass in the function handle to `myMethod` in this case, since this new function can't create a `myParent` variable.

Comment: yes it's possible. Doing this creates a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). In fact this was one way to achieve [OOP encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) before `classdef`-style objects were introduced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
function myP = myParent()

    myP.My_Method = @myMethod;

    function myMethod()
        s=dbstack;
        fprintf('Hello from %s!\n',s(1).name);
    end
end
```

Running it as follows:

```
>> myP = myParent()
myP = 
    My_Method: @myParent/myMethod
>> feval(myP.My_Method)
Hello from myParent/myMethod!
>> myP.My_Method()
Hello from myParent/myMethod!
```

It is also fine to run it from another function:

```
% newfun.m
function newfun(hfun)
feval(hfun)
```

Test:

```
>> newfun(myP.My_Method)
Hello from myParent/myMethod!
```

Depending on what you are doing, this should be enough.  Note that each handle you create is unique since [it contains information about externally scoped variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html#f4-64094) (variables pulled in the parent):

> When you create a function handle for a nested function, that handle stores not only the name of the function, but also the values of externally scoped variables.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the @myMethod in my original code. I have that. What I really want to do is be able to create a function handler to the My_Method call. Any ideas?

Comment: You do get a function handle, but you have to get first via `myParent`, as an output argument.  The output variable `myP` is not an instance of `myParent`, just a struct containing the function handle you need.